# Push lua function as table member from C API

Tags: c, lua

Well there are no problems to push C function as function member or register C function as lua function with **lua_register(L, lua_func_name, c_func);**

But how tell lua what i want to pass **luaFoo()** as function callback param for "foober" from C?
lua_pushcfunction - pushes C function, lua_pushstring pushes just a plain string, so callback field became a string, not a function.

Lua Code:

```
CALLBACKS = {};
FOO = 0;

function luaFoo()
FOO = FOO + 1;
end;

function addCallback(_name, _callback)
CALLBACKS[_name] = _callback;
end;

function doCallback(_name)
CALLBACKS[_name]();
end;
```

C code:

```
static int c_foo(lua_State* l)
{
  printf("FOO\n");
  return 0;
}

/*load lua script*/;
lua_State* l = /*get lua state*/;
lua_getglobal(l, "addCallback");
lua_pushstring(l, "foober");
//What push for luaFoo()
lua_pushcfunction(l, c_foo);
lua_call(l, 2, 0);

lua_getglobal(l, "doCallback");
lua_pushstring(l, "foober");
lua_call(l, 1, 0);
```

Similiar - if i get C functions which already registered with **lua_register**, how pass them as callback param from C. So we register **c_foo** => c_foo exist as lua function, how to tell what we want to pass **"c_foo"** as callback func param.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember that:

```
function luaFoo()
  ...
end
```

is equivalent to this, in Lua:

```
luaFoo = function()
  ...
end
```

Therefore, your question ultimately boils down to, "I have a value in the global table. How do I push it onto the stack?" The fact that this value is a function is *irrelevant*; a function value in Lua is no different from an integer value, which is no different than a string value. Obviously you can *do* different things with them, but you just want to copy them around. That works the same regardless of what the value is.

The function you're looking for is [`lua_getglobal`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_getglobal).

As for your second question, you can do it in one of two ways. You can either get the function value you registered from the global table, or you can simply re-register it with `lua_pushcfunction`. Since you're not using upvalues, re-registering it doesn't really have any downsides.

Oh, and one more thing, on code style. Lua doesn't require `;` at the end of statements. You can do it (to make C-native programmers feel more comfortable), but it's not necessary.